# "Preguntas sin respuesta" que sí tienen respuestas publicadas

Tags: soporte, preguntas-no-contestadas

Seleccionando en el menú principal "Unanswered Questions" (es decir: [así](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/unanswered)) salen 19 preguntas que no tienen respuesta.

En cambio seleccionando "Questions" y subseleccionando "Unanswered" (es decir: [así](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered)) aparecen 22 preguntas en total, ya que se incluyen, además, 3 **preguntas que si tienen respuestas publicads**: [raiders-of-the-lost-roll-en-busca-del-rollo-perdido](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21037/raiders-of-the-lost-roll-en-busca-del-rollo-perdido) con 2 respuestas, [subjuntivo-main-clause-present-subordinate-in-past](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21497/subjuntivo-main-clause-present-subordinate-in-past) con 2 respuestas y [significaban-lo-mismo-vosotros-y-vos-otros-en-el-siglo-xv](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18636/significaban-lo-mismo-vosotros-y-vos-otros-en-el-siglo-xv) con 1 respuesta.

¿Es esto un fallo? ¿Hay tal vez algún matiz que se me escapa y por eso se incluyen preguntas que si tienen respuesta publicada en la segunda forma de búsqueda?

Answer (score 2):

Esto es normal. Esto, además, es lioso y se presta a confusión.

"Unanswered" muestra todas aquellas preguntas que no tienen ninguna respuesta con puntaje positivo. Eso es lo que ocurre en todas aquellas que no tienen respuestas (obvio) y en las tres que mencionas.

Todos estamos de acuerdo en que el nombre "unanswered"  es confuso. De todos modos, sigue cierta lógica: asume como respuesta todo aquello que haya sido recibido positivamente y, por ende, una pregunta sin respuesta es aquella en que no ha habido aún ninguna.